# Can we pick up the file from Google drive and upload this into Salesforce using Apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce

we have a csv file in Google drive which has sample data(sample field).I need to write an apex code to pick this file from this Google drive and load data into temporary table in salesforce. The idea is if the file is stored on Google drive can we pick up the file from salesforce and upload this data.

Comment: I have been working on a project to call the Google Drive API from Apex, it uses random domains ultimately to read the file, this causes issues in Apex as the Remote Site needs to be created in each case, which becomes impractical, we are currently planning on using a Herok REST API proxy to do the read indirectly for us. In short its not that straight forward we are finding....

Comment: @AndrewFawcett How are you using heroku rest api? Are you calling google drive api from heroku?

Comment: @AndrewFawcett Is it possible to retrieve blob data using google app script?